# When using an XElement once, declare inline or create its own object?

Tags: c#, xelement

When I am using an XElement once, should I declare it inline e.g.

```
user.name = new XElement("Name", "John Doe");
```

or declare the XElement on its own line, e.g.

```
XElement elem =  new XElement("Name", "John Doe");
user.name = elem;
```

Comment: Which one do you and/or your coworkers find more readable? Go with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever you like. The compiler will optimize it to the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

user.name = new XElement("Name", "John Doe");

is fine if you are only going to use it once. saves a few bytes for the extra pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that you don't have a meaningful name ("elem") for the XElement variable is telling. The XElement only has meaning assigned to name, so I'd do it inline.